# need to show Child form below Panel [WinForms] C#

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I am creating a windows desktop application and I need to show Forms below the Panel as shown in the image below.

Is there any option with that I can achieve the same?

Here is my code:

```
form_change_password change_password = new form_change_password();
change_password.MdiParent = this;
change_password.BringToFront();
change_password.TopMost = true;
change_password.Show();
```

Image:
[image]

I need as below:
[image]

Comment: There is the option of manually setting windows forms `StartPosition` unless you want them movable on mouse click and drag.

Comment: It looks like your "sticky" menu is also a Form (I can see it overlap some part of your main form it shouldn't if it were to be a control). Make a custom control if you want these panels to remain inside your main form.

Comment: @Fixation yes, a sticky menu is a Panel control, can you please share some links for the example to do the same?

Comment: Check out this project which demonstrates a solution similair to what you are trying to achieve: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C

Comment: Pretty doubtful you actually like MDI.  But it can only be "sticky" if you put the toolbar panel on the MdiParent form and set its Dock property to Top.  You'll have to set the child form's StartupPosition and Location properties to get it to show where you want it.  Considerable odds that you actually meant to create UserControls.

Comment: I am aware of the tool strip but I want icon large as shown in the image above.